# Sorting an integer array of 100 elements having only 3 elements in it

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

Suppose I have an array of 100 numbers. The only distinct values in the array are 1, 2 and 3. The values are randomly ordered throughout the array. For instance, the array might be populated as:

```
int values[100];

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    values[i] = 1 + rand() % 3;
```

How can I efficiently sort an array like this?

Comment: Voting to close - arrays are contiguous by nature - sounds like homework

Comment: @Adrian: i mean to say not placed in continuous index places

Comment: @AdrianCornish: I would disagree. This is a perfectly legitimate question. The OP just phrased it strangely.

Comment: Its one of the interview questions i read. BTW Mike has changed exact query. Question is: sorting array of 100 elements having 3 elements filled with numbers and other places are not initialized or having array of segments.

Comment: @MikeBantegui In your programming career when have you ever been asked to solve a problem similar to this - it is patently artificial.

Comment: I assume you don't know where the numbers are, but you can tell a number from uninitialized memory (I won't ask how). What's wrong with 1) find those three numbers (O(n)), 2)sort them (O(1) and negligible), 3) put them in [0],[1],[2]?

Answer (score 11):

The fastest solution is not to "sort" at all:

- Run through the array and count the number of occurrences of 1,2 and 3. These counts should hopefully fit in registers...
- Fill the array with the right number of 1s, 2s and 3s, overwriting whatever is there already.

At the end you will have a fully sorted array.

In general, this can be a useful O(n) sorting algorithm when you have a very small range of possible values compared to the size of the array.

Comment: This is called a bucket sort and is the simplest form of a radix sort if you're interested in some further reading.

Comment: @mikera: i don't have all array with value 1,2,3. In array of 100 it has only 3 elements initialized and rest fields are uninitialized or you can say it has segments or any garbage value.

Comment: @ExploringApple - the technique will still work if you ignore uninitialised values. But if you know that you will only have one each of 1,2 and 3 then you don't even need to count them - just output 1, 2 and 3 into the first three elements of the array.

Comment: @PeteFordham: I would say this is the "counting sort", which is the simplist form of a bucket sort, and bucket sorts are a form of radix sort.

Comment: Huh? the array contains uninitialized values? That makes an exact solution impossible.

Answer (score 2):

[Dutch National flag algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem) is the commonly cited algorithm for this and is actually the partition step in one of the variants of quicksort (1 corresponds to less than, 2 to equal to and 3 to greater than). In that variant, you don't need to sort the middle portion.